# how to show x-axis values at top instead of bottom in kendo chart

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I want to move x axis at the top for range bar chart in kendo chart for angular 2

[sample chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QOx4.png)

[image]

I am using https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/series-types/range-bar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels>` inside the `<kendo-chart-category-axis-item>`. Then set the position to `end`. The position parameter value must be of type `AxisLabelsPosition`. So import it from the `@progress/kendo-angular-charts` package.

*For example:*

```
<kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels [rotation]="-60" [position]="position"></kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels>

public position: AxisLabelsPosition = "end";
```

Also the label rotation will be affected by setting the position. To get the correct rotation of labels, remove `[labels]="{ rotation: 'auto' }` from `kendo-chart-category-axis-item` and set `[rotation]` inside the `kendo-chart-category-axis-item-labels`.

[Refer this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k6fsmd?file=app/app.component.ts).